# Disabling options in select

Tags: php, jquery

I have a select with options. I want to disable the options based on ids. Some options have the same id. When i disable the options, it only disables just one id (the first option from the db).

How do I get the jquery to disable all options with id = 0

**File.php**

```
<select id="select_id" name="select_id">
   <option id="<?php echo $item->part; ?>"><?php echo $item->part; ?></option>
</select>
<script>
 $('#0').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
</script>
```

Comment: If you have more than one option with the id=0 your HTML isn't valid as ids have to be unique. Better use classes instead or write the value to a data attribute.

Comment: Also, you probably want to use option `value` attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the same id to multiple elements is not a good practice. I would recommend you use class in this case, instead of id. And then to disable all you would do :

```
$(".0").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

html :

```
<select id="select_id" name="select_id">
   <option id="sel1">01</option>
   <option id="sel2">02</option>
   <option id="sel3">03</option>
   <option id="sel1">04</option>
</select>
```

jquery :

```
let searchId = 'sel1'
$('#select_id option[id="'+searchId+'"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
```

jsfiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/bmr1zsq9/

I think it's not a good way to have multiple ids with same values.
You should use name or value or class value to have a valid html

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You can either use class attribute or custom attribute like data and you can call it using jQuery selectors.

```
<select id="select_id" name="select_id">
   <option data-id="<?php echo $item->part; ?>"><?php echo $item->part; ?></option>
</select>
<script>
 $('select option[data-id="0"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
</script>
```

> *I think you missed to add value attribute*

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is because you are using ID's, the DOM expects ID's to be unique thus will not operate recursively.  Please update your code to utilize html classes and not ID's.

I.E.

```
<select id="select_id" name="select_id">
   <option value="val1" class="sel1">01</option>
   <option value="val2" class="sel2">02</option>
   <option value="val3" class="sel3">03</option>
   <option value="val4" class="sel1">04</option>
</select>
```

Also please make sure to set a value to your options for best practice.